How to prove $AdS^3$ is a Lorentzian manifold?
Consider the real vector space $\mathbb R^{2,2} = (\mathbb R^{4}, b)$ with the non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form of signature $(2,2)$ $$b(x,y) = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2-x_3y_3-x_4y_4$$
Consider $AdS^3$ (quadric model) be the set $$AdS^3 = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid b(x,x) = -1\}$$
I have proved that tangent space at $x \in AdS^3$, $T_x AdS^3 = x^\perp$ and $b\Big|_{x^\perp}$ has signature $(2,1)$ is a Lorentzian metric, let denote it by $g_{AdS^3}$. Then $(AdS^3, g_{AdS^3})$. is a Lorentzian manifold of dimension $3$.
Let $\pi: \mathbb R^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R P^3}$ be the the canonical projection, then we define the projective model of anti-de Sitter space as $$\text{AdS}^3 = \{[x]\in \mathbb{RP}^3 \mid b(x,x) <0\} = AdS^3/ x \sim -x$$ Thus $\pi: AdS^3 \rightarrow \text{AdS}^3$ is a $2$-sheeted covering.  I want to prove $\text{AdS}^3$  is a Lorentzian manifold.
I think that $T_{[x]}\text{AdS}^3$ can be identified with $x^\perp$. Hence it follows. But my question is can anyone  use $\pi$ (local isometry etc) to prove Lorentzian manifold?
